# jquery fullcalendar hide certain hours

Tags: jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I want to use jquery fullcalendar but I want to hide certain hours.
I want to show the calendar from 8.00am->11.00am and from 16:00pm->19:00pm

So the hours between 11:00am and 16:00pm must be 'hidden'.

I don't see an option to do this :
How can I force this ?

thx in advance
Kristof

Comment: Sorry, but can you, please post what you've done so far??

Comment: @Nani : Because I don't know how to do the hiding I show from 8am->19pm using mintime and maxtime

Comment: fullcalendar dont support show/hidden range of hours. Check hour in callback event when click.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to modify fullcalendar source because you want to be up to date with official branch.

Then the only way is to hide appropriate rows (hours) after fullcalendar initialization with javascript:

```
//hide rows with unused hours. Class names can be found in html source of
//rendered fullcalendar (fc-slotxx)
for(var i=0; i<gapshours.length; i++)
{
    var gapclass = '.' + gapsclasses[i];
    $(gapclass).hide()           
}

//display hours for clipped borders
for(var i=0; i<sethourhours.length; i++)
{
    var hourclass = '.' + sethourclasses[i] + ' th'
    $(hourclass).text(sethourhours[i]);        
}
```

After that you must remember of clipping and moving events' periods just for view purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very helpful to see your code; here's my best guess.

In your fullCalendar initialization code, I would use an event generating function (see [event generating function](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/))

```
events: function(start,end,callback){
  //get your data from wherever you're getting it
  var events = some_ajax_method(start, end);

  //filter it down to the times you want to show
  events = $.map(events, function(event){
    if (event meets time criteria)
      return event
    else
      return null;
  });
  callback(events);
}
```